# Laravel 7 - The Route is perfect here but not returning the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

In route-

```
Route::get('/portfoliodetail/{name}/{id}', 'HomePage@portfolioDetail')->name('portfoliodetail');
```

In controller-

```
public function portfolioDetail($id , $name)
```

{
}

In blade-

```
<a href="{{url('portfoliodetail' . '/' . $portfolio->caption . '/' . $portfolio->id )}}">
```

Comment: Swap controller method's arguments : `public function portfolioDetail($name ,$id)`

Comment: What's inside HomePage@portfolioDetail?

Comment: can you provide your HomePage controller

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reverse the following:

```
public function portfolioDetail($name, id)
```

Your call in blade should work as is but you can also call the named route so that way you change the url later without having to hunt it down.

```
<a href="{{ route('portfoliodetail', $portfolio->caption, $portfolio->id) }}">
    Link
</a
```